# PCL : computing FPFH at given keypoints

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose i have a bunch of keypoints detected by 2D SIFT or SURF and i want to calculate FPFH descriptors at those keypoints. How can i do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57021/pcl-:-computing-fpfh-at-given-keypoints/) by [Pavel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4351/pavel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [PCL tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/fpfh_estimation.php) to show how to do it

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pavel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4351/pavel/) on 2013-03-11**:
@kalectro: thank you but I'd like to compute FPFH for single points and not for an entire point cloud. How can i do this?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-11**:
As for as I know FPFH descriptors need a pointcloud to work with. So do the following:
If you have a bunch of keypoints, just create a new empty point cloud and add the keypoints one by one.

**Comment by [Pavel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4351/pavel/) on 2013-03-11**:
@kalectro. Thank you again. I thought of that but for computing a local descriptor the points around a keypoint should be needed as well. Am i wrong?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-11**:
You are right, I did not read the tutotial and only assumed it would work like the SHOT descriptor. Try to ask this question on pcl-users.org

**Comment by [Pavel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4351/pavel/) on 2013-03-11**:
Already did that but unfortunately no one has answered (http://www.pcl-users.org/Computing-FPFH-at-given-keypoints-td4026504.html). Thank you anyway.

**Comment by [hamed12](https://answers.ros.org/users/89096/hamed12/) on 2021-11-07**:
how to save descriptor output in pcl
move descriptor output to the matlab